# Ubuntu / MySQL / Percona XtraBackup gives error "sh: 1: xtrabackup_55: not found"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, percona, backup, xtrabackup

Hello I installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS on a fresh box.

This installed MySQL 5.5.29.

I installed percona-xtrabackup-2.0.6-521.tar.gz, and moved the executables to /usr/bin/

But innobackupex is giving an error: "sh: 1: xtrabackup_55: not found"

---

```
david@server1:/usr/bin$ sudo innobackupex --user=root --password=123 /home/david/dbb/
[sudo] password for david: 

InnoDB Backup Utility v1.5.1-xtrabackup; Copyright 2003, 2009 Innobase Oy
and Percona Ireland Ltd 2009-2012.  All Rights Reserved.

This software is published under
the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2, June 1991.

130401 12:17:04  innobackupex: Starting mysql with options:  --password=xxxxxxxx --user='root' --unbuffered --
130401 12:17:04  innobackupex: Connected to database with mysql child process (pid=1488)
130401 12:17:10  innobackupex: Connection to database server closed
IMPORTANT: Please check that the backup run completes successfully.
           At the end of a successful backup run innobackupex
           prints "completed OK!".

innobackupex: Using mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
innobackupex: Using mysql server version Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

sh: 1: xtrabackup_55: not found
innobackupex: fatal error: no 'mysqld' group in MySQL options
```

---

The files are present and executable:

```
david@server1:/usr/bin$ ls -l inno*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  108823 Mar 19 14:24 innobackupex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 david david     12 Mar 19 14:24 innobackupex-1.5.1 -> innobackupex
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root   10096 Jan 16 17:24 innochecksum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  400192 Jan 16 17:24 innotop
david@server1:/usr/bin$ 
david@server1:/usr/bin$ ls -l xtra*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9799993 Mar 19 14:21 xtrabackup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  8361704 Mar 19 14:24 xtrabackup_51
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12699861 Mar 19 14:15 xtrabackup_55
david@server1:/usr/bin$
```

---

Path is correct:

```
david@server1:/usr/bin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

---

I get the same results if I run

```
innobackupex 
./innobackupex 
sudo innobackupex 
sudo ./innobackupex
```

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Dumb question, but have you tried this while not sitting inside `/usr/bin`?  i.e., cd to a different directory first.

Comment: yes I tried that

Comment: what is your server bit? Is it 32 or 64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your server bit if it is 32 bit and if you try to install 64bit package percona's xtrabackup . It would end up throwing such error messages.

Comment: Ubuntu server was 64 bit, but had installed Perconas 32 bit version.  Installing correct Percona software fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, looks like you don't have [mysqld] section in /etc/my.cnf file

Comment: Yes is is there.
I think the real error is the one that is above:
"sh: 1: xtrabackup_55: not found"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you make a backup with an older version of xtrabackup you need to restore it with an older version.  From "yum provides *bin/xtrabackup_55" this is the most current version that contains that program.  If I remove the current version and install with this:

## yum install percona-xtrabackup-2.0.7-552.rhel6.x86_64

Then my recovery worked without throwing the above error.

Comment: Obviously the ubuntu user would have to use "apt-get install" instead of yum :D